# Why does iterating through the loop is not working

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question, I am trying to complete an exercise where I enter `1,2,3` and the output would say: `One, Two Three`. The following code is not working.  My logic is to enter the numbers, `1,2,3` and then run a for loop through the input.  Thank you so much!

```
phone = input("Phone")
digitmap = {
    1: "One",
    2: "Two",
    3: "Three",
    4: "Four"
}
for i in phone:
  output = digitmap[i]
  print(output)
```

Comment: You're looping over characters of type `str`, e.g. `"1"` instead of `1`. This is something you can determine by `print(type(i))` or `print(repr(i))`. You can fix it by changing the first line to: `phone = int(input("Phone"))`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq but that'd make the whole string an integer and then the OP wouldn't be able to loop over it character by character...(not to mention if they're intending to enter it as comma delimited - it'll raise a ValueError exception as it can't convert to an int anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that your input is a list of `int` to look up in your dictionary. So we first declare `phone` as a list, and then fill it using the method below:

`[int(x) for x in input("Phone\n").split(',')]`

Then, might end up with a dictionary that is out of order. Perhaps your `digitmap` looks like:

```
digitmap = {
    3: "Three",
    4: "Four",
    1: "One",
    2: "Two"
}
```

At that point, your index based reference would fail. Instead, we should use the [`dict.get()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) method which returns the value for the key in the hashmap

```
phone = []
# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-input-a-comma-separated-string/
phone = [int(x) for x in input("Phone\n").split(',')] 
digitmap = {
    1: "One",
    2: "Two",
    3: "Three",
    4: "Four"
}
for i in phone:
  output = digitmap.get(i)
  print(output)
```

Looks like:

```
C:\Users\wundermahn\Desktop>python stack_example.py
Phone
1,2,3
One
Two
Three
```